# Global variable in Javascript back to it's first value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that get two parameters and do different stuff according to which step it's on.

So it's like a short quest with four steps.

```
var  stp=1;
var vocabulary= new Array();
vocabulary['greatings']= ['привет','здорово','здравствуй'];
vocabulary['grQuestions']= ['как дела','что нового','как здоровье','как поживаешь'];
vocabulary['qrAnswers']= ['нормально как сам','спасибо хорошо','потихоньку','отлично'];

function myMission(stp,str) {
  switch (stp) {
  case 1:
    {
      if (jQuery.inArray(str, vocabulary['greatings'])!==-1) {
        stp+=1;
        $('.stp').html(stp);
        $('.answer').html('Привет!');
      } else {
        $('.stp').html(stp);
        $('.answer').html('Не понимаю');
      }
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    alert("23");
    break;
  case 3:
    alert("24");
    break;
}
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checker').click(function() {
    var str = $('.yourVoice').val();
    myMission(stp,str);
  });
});
```

The problem is that `stp` always back to `1`
how can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look at jsfiddle.net and set up an example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing the value of stp to the function as a parameter.  It then operates on its local copy and not the global variable.

To fix it, remove the stp parameter from the function definition and any calls to it.

```
function myMission(str) { ...

myMission(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you complicate yourself using the same name for a global variable `var  stp=1;` and a function argument `function myMission(stp,str)` ? The variable you're editing is the local one to the function scope, the global is not being affected at all.

If I understood well, you don't need the argument, and should only use the global variable.

```
function myMission(str) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes!! Thanks! I just saw it!

Answer (score 0):

When you do stp+=1  inside a function with a parameter with the same name, you are not working anymore with the global var, but you are working on the parameter that actually is a copy of the original var, so you are working on a totally different thing.

The solution can be to change the name of the parameter of the function:

```
function myMission(stp_another_name,str) {
...
```

Anyway if you want to work on the global var you can omit to pass it to function as parameter

```
function myMission(str) {
...

...
myMission(str);
```

Of course according the purpose of your code